# Does C# 8 annotate nullable properties and parameters?

Tags: c#, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

I'm curious about how nullable reference types work, not in your own codebase, but with an already compiled library. Will C# be able to know if a property or parameter is nullable, perhaps checking the existance of some compiler-added attribute?

Comment: As written in [ms doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/) nullables are types: `Nullable<T>`where T is a value type. There is no need of a special attribute.

Comment: @H.G.Sandhagen He's talking about nullable *reference* types, new concept and support in C# 8, not the same.

Comment: @H.G.Sandhagen in the unreleased C# 8 we get new things like `public string? myString {get; set;}` I have no clue if anyone will really benefit from this when it's released with existing datasources or logic structures...

Comment: Yes, it will add an attribute if you use `?` after a reference type. An already compiled assembly (that is, not compiled with C# 8) will not have those attributes. Whether the compiler will treat that assembly differently, or just assume everything that says it returns a reference returns a non-null value, I don't know, which is why I don't post an answer. You can check out the result here: https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgZgpghgLgrgJwgZwLQDk4BstWFiAJQkiQDsBjCAFQE8AHFAGhhAEssAfAAQAYACbgEYA3AFgAUNwDMggEz8AwvwDek/hsGzuAFn4BZABQBKVes0XhATkMBxCDHRQAthBPHxEiwF9zGv1qCQrwA/Pz2ji5upgC8AHz8AETUKDCJnt5AA==

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Thanks for the sharplab link, it answers the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like the behaviour has changed between VS2019 Preview 1 and Preview 2, potentially due to the way that the nullable context can be changed. There's no longer a per-assembly or per-type attribute. It's possible it'll change again, of course,

In VS2019 Preview 2, each part of a member that expresses either nullable or non-nullable information (parameters and return type) is separately attributed using a `NullableAttribute` which is included in the assembly itself if necessary. This attribute has two constructors:

```
NullableAttribute(byte)
NullableAttribute(byte[])
```

The `byte` form is used when every aspect of the nullability for that parameter/return type is the same. The `byte[]` is used when there's a mixture of nullability for a single element, due to generics or arrays. In both cases, 1 is used for "not-nullable", 2 is used for "nullable". So for example:

```
public class Test
{
    public string? Foo(string input) { ... }

    public List<string>? Bar() { ... }
}
```

is compiled to:

```
public class Test
{
    [return:Nullable(2)]
    public string Foo([Nullable(1)] string input) { ... }

    [return: Nullable(new byte[] { 1, 2 })]
    public List<string> Bar() { ... }
}
```

This allows any code examining the assembly (whether that's the compiler using it as a reference, or other tooling) to understand the intention on a per-member basis.

I've written more about this in [a blog post](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2019/02/10/nullableattribute-and-c-8/) but that should be enough to get the gist.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, if the library has been compiled using a C# 8.0 compiler with nullable reference types turned on, the compiler will be able to recognize which values were marked as nullable.

For example, consider this code:

```
class C
{
    string NotNullProperty { get; set; }
    string? NullProperty { get; set; }

    void M(string notNullParameter, string? nullParameter) {}
}
```

[It compiles roughly into:](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwD4GIB2BXANliwtwAEcaeBAsAFBUACATIQMJUDeVhHhNAjAAyEA5APYwB2LAAUEQgA6IYAT0ItCAczgwA3ISgbtAX3acevAPyDxU2fKUr1WnXsKHKnQkY40ALIQCyAChNCNBExHAkIBAgwDUQAGi4+c0xwyOjYhABKZRd9IA=)

```
[NonNullTypes(true)]
class C
{
    string NotNullProperty { get; set; }

    [Nullable]
    string NullProperty { get; set; }

    void M(string notNullParameter, [Nullable] string nullParameter) { }
}
```

Notice that the nullable property and parameter are marked as `[Nullable]` and that the whole class is marked as `[NonNullTypes(true)]`, indicating that the nullable reference types feature is enabled for it.

On the other hand, if the code was compiled without the feature, it will be considered "null-oblivious". This means that the compiler will not produce null-related warnings when you're working with that code.

Comment: Update: The `[NonNullTypes]` approach was abandoned in favor of dedicated syntax: `#nullable enable`

Comment: @JulienCouvreur I'm talking about the metadata representation here and AFAICT, that still uses attributes (since there is no such thing as preprocessor directives in metadata).

Comment: Oops. Yes, we still use Nullable attribute, but we no longer use NonNullTypes attribute (even in metadata). `Nullable` now stores an array of bytes instead of bools (0, 1 and 2 for three states). 
The encoding is described in https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/docs/features/nullable-reference-types.md#annotations

Comment: I've written up `Nullable` as an answer now. Although I haven't seen the compiler apply a 0 in any case yet... I guess I'd need to work out a situation where part of an element is oblivious.

Answer (score 1):

In [Take C# 8.0 for a spin](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/12/05/take-c-8-0-for-a-spin/) by Mads Torgersen (Program Manager for the C# language at Microsoft) he says:

> If you call code that didn’t have the nullable reference types feature on (maybe it was compiled before the feature even existed), then we cannot know what the intent of that code was: it doesn’t distinguish between nullable and nonnullable – we say that it is "null-oblivious". So we give it a pass; we simply don’t warn on such calls.

So no, it appears they won't flag it, so you won't get any sort of compiler warning. So  when consuming code prior to C# 8, it seems like you'll have to do some research to find out whether the reference could contain null or not, instead of relying on the type system and compiler to warn you.

Comment: Testing with Sharplab, it seems that methods that say they return a string (ie. they're not using `?`) don't get annotated at all, which leads me to think that methods in an older assembly are simply assumed to always return a reference and never `null`, just as if the method was specifically written to do so in C# 8.

Comment: Yes, which means that when consuming older code, we'll have to be extra careful handling it still. Even more careful than usual, because we might get lulled into a false sense of security.

Comment: I agree, will be interesting to see how this plays out.